# Mapping json object with a schema in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, mapping, lodash

I am using nodejs.

I am having the following problem -

There is a very big json object which i want to map to a much smaller object with a specific format which i will be using later on.

I want to have specific schemas which i will be able to use on that big object, each schema will have its own purpose. I want to be able to customize the structure via those schemas and no where else.

I was searching for a library which can help me with that.

I found one via npm which is called deep-map.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-map

I played with it for a bit and it seem to answer my basic needs.

But i also going to be needing to do some more complex mapping.

A simplified example -

```
"testObj": { "myArr": [ {"type": "x", name:"test1"}, {"type": "y", name:"test2"}] }
```

and i need to look in `myArr` only for the name for which `type` equals `x`.
So basically i need some sort of for each loop and if term in between.

Since deep-map uses lodash/template i thought maybe there is a way to use the capabilities of lodash to solve this problem but so far i didnt find how to combine those two ( lodash + deep-map ) to solve the more complex mapping.

I am also open to other libraries which might help me with this problem.

Comment: Maybe [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Lodash has an [at method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#at) that will do the simple cases of this. It lets you specify things like `field.subfieldThatsAnArray[1].subsubfield` and get the value.

For less of a "built in your own" solution, there's a couple bits of tech that might be interesting here too:

- [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
- [SelectTransform](https://github.com/SelectTransform/st.js)

There's some others out there, but JSONPath is used some other places in the space, and SelectTransform just looks cool.